# Component is not being rendered from ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, babeljs

Context:

In my dissertation, I decided to use react to load a table into the webpage, where a user is able to choose what room to go into. Right now I am using SWIG (tempting engine) to make the table as the page is loaded, but I realized that if I use React, updating it would be eraser then building it over again. (Also its a great way to learn react as I do want to use it later). Before I get there I decided to play around with react, and chose to use babel to render my component. Ignore the messy code as lots of it will be tidied up and changed later.

Problem:

The file is not loading at all. I first followed [this](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env) tutorial to install babel, then used the code found on [the reactjs tutorial page](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) to load some test code in a file called `test.js`. I then used babel to convert it into jsx code.

The file is being found as it is not showing any errors, but the its content is not being loaded at all. Not even the `console.log("here")` is being output to console.

My files:

roomChoose.html:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Choose a room to play!</title>
        <script
            type="text/javascript"
            src="../../javascript/roomChooseComponents/roomChooseFunctions.js"
        ></script>

        <script
            type="text/javascript"
            src="../../javascript/lib/jquery.js"
        ></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/roomChoose.css" />
        <script
            type="text/javascript"
            src="../../javascript/roomChooseComponents/askForPass.js"
        ></script>

        <script src="../socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                document.getElementById("roomPass").readOnly = true;
            });

            const socket = io.connect();
            socket.on("connect", () => {
                let obj = {
                    room: "roomChoose",
                    name: "undecided"
                };
                socket.emit("room", obj);
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="like_button_container"></div>
        <div class="roomTableDiv" id="roomTableDiv">
            {% if rooms.length == 0%}
            <p>No public rooms! Why dont you make one?</p>
            {%else%}
            <p>Public rooms:</p>
            <table id="roomTable">
                <tr>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>Room Name</th>
                    <th>Player Number</th>
                    <th>State</th>
                </tr>
                <tbody id="#roomTabletbodyID">
                    {% for r in rooms %} {% if r.roomName != "generalChat" &&
                    r.playerNumber < 4 && r.roomName != "roomChoose" %}
                    <tr>
                        {%if r.roomPassword != null %}
                        <td>
                            <button onclick="askForPassword('{{r.roomName}}',true)">
                                Join
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        {% else %}
                        <td>
                            <button onclick="askForPassword('{{r.roomName}}',false)">
                                Join
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        {% endif %}
                        <td>"{{r.roomName}}"</td>
                        <td>{{r.playerNumber}}/4</td>
                        {%if r.roomPassword != null %}
                        <td>
                            Private
                        </td>
                        {% else %}
                        <td>
                            Public
                        </td>
                        {% endif %}
                    </tr>
                    {% endif %} {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <p>
                Alternatively, you can create your own room here and make it private:
            </p>
            {%endif%}
        </div>
        <div class="cont">
            <form
                action="/board/createNew"
                method="post"
                id="roomCreate"
                onsubmit="return checkForm(this)"
            >
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    name="private"
                    id="private"
                    onclick="hideShowPasswordFeild(this)"
                />Private room? <br />
                Roomname:
                <input type="text" name="roomName" id="roomName" />
                <div class="roomPasswordDiv" id="roomPasswordDiv">
                    Password:
                    <input type="text" name="roomPass" id="roomPass" />
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Create room</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script
            src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"
            crossorigin
        ></script>
        <script
            src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"
            crossorigin
        ></script>

        <!-- Load our React component. -->
        <!-- <script src="../../javascript/roomChooseComponents/components/chooseRoomTable.js"></script> -->
        <script type="javascript/text" src="/html/board/test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
class LikeButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { liked: false };
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.liked) {
            return "You liked this.";
        }

        return e(
            "button",
            { onClick: () => this.setState({ liked: true }) },
            "Like"
        );
    }
}
$(document).ready(() => {
    const domContainer = document.querySelector("#like_button_container");
    ReactDOM.render(React.CreateComponent(LikeButton), domContainer);
    console.log("here");
});
```

[My file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frG4H.png)

[The rendered file from node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUWyW.png)

The files address is http://localhost:3000/board, where /board is the default route of my `board.js` router file.

If any files are needed please just say and I will be happy to provide. I have been stressing over this for a week now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are jus starting to learn I'd advice use [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started)

Comment: I cant really transfer my whole diss to this. I just need it to use react to create two table elements, one here one elsewhere. I have actually done that at first to play with react, but im having trouble adding it to existing app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this was when I was still v green and didnt know what I was really doing. Here what I was trying to do was just insert a bit of react into plain js.

React does not work that way. Dont be me.

Answer (score 0):

The file is loading. You do not see the `console.log("here")` because `React.CreateComponent` is not a fuction, it must be `React.createElement` and the `e` varibale in the `render()` method is not define too.

Here is your `test.js`

```
const e = React.createElement;

class LikeButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { liked: false };
    }
    render() {
        if (this.state.liked) {
            return 'You liked this.';
        }
        return e(
            'button',
            { onClick: () => this.setState({ liked: true }) },
            'Like'
        );
    }
}


$(document).ready(() => {
    const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
    ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton), domContainer);
    console.log("here");
});
```

See the full example from the react documentation [here](https://gist.github.com/gaearon/6668a1f6986742109c00a581ce704605)

Comment: Did not work. The console.log("here") is still not being printed and nothing is rendered

Comment: [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-water-z3v06) is a small setup of your express app using your file structure and the SWIG engine. In the browser section navigate to https://z3v06.sse.codesandbox.io/board then look at the console